# Web designer vs Front-end developer

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, frontend

After reading some job openings, I'm really 'confused' about the definition of web design and front-end development. Several companies are mixing those 2 in the most creative propositions. Nowadays you hear 'it's the same' too often, but in my opinion that's too simple.

**Front-end Development**
(focus on code)

- CSS
- Javascript
- HTML5
- etc.

**Webdesign:** (focus on graphics)

- Photoshop
- Flash
- etc.

What's your opinion?

Comment: In my personal opinion the site was richer when this kind of questions were allowed... but that's not the case anymore so you could expect this to be closed soon

Comment: I agree with @ClaudioRedi. This will no doubt be closed as it's opinion based and there is probably no definitive answer, however I think it's a good question and could generate good debate.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about job titles and names of things, not programming even in a broad sense.

Comment: this question would likely be more welcome on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ClaudioRedi: There is a large supply of excellent questions that have valid answers that simply don't belong on this site. This site has a relatively narrow focus. That's why it's good. If it would degenerate into a mishmash of things, people would stop coming here, and we don't want that, I don't think.

Comment: @Kuba Ober: I believe the site has its own dynamic and the community took a different direction for the site than the expected one some years ago. Then  the site became much more restrictive and I belive that reduced the interest of the community. Just an opinion though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In many web design agencies you'll have a graphic designer, web designer/front-end developer and a back-end developer.

Since the graphic designer will be focusing on the aesthetics, the job of the web designer is to translate that design into a real website through code, perhaps with some additional visual input.

However, if a website has already been built, a front-end developer may maintain that site, add more functionality and make improvements. They are 'developing' the site.

Furthermore, front-end coding that focuses on functionality is not visual design and not always visual based, so it is therefore less web design and more front-end development. For example, building jQuery plugins, web apps and browser-side web-based programmes.

If a person is coding the websites AND doing the graphics for them, they would certainly be called a web designer.